# localStorage or something else?

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I am trying to figure out the best way to store dynamically loaded html within a `div` for the user's next visit.

I've read a bit about `localStorage` and to possibly stringify this info, however, I am not very clear on the implementation.

However, with the above said, here is what I am doing currently and what I would like to accomplish.

I am using code like:

```
$(function() {
    $('.cordpass').click(function() {
        var collection = $(this).find('span').load(this.href + ' #cords');
        $('#summary').append( $(collection) );
        return false;
    });
});
```

This is essentially grabbing info from another page and adding it to a `div` with the ID of `#summary`. This can be done from multiple objects on a page (they are all on a map). Anyway, the user can sort and all kinds of stuff. That works great for my needs. However, I'd like to save the HTML within `#summary` so that the next time the user visits, the HTML is there.

What is the best way to do that? Is `localStorage` a good fit for me, or am I completely misunderstanding its use, and is there another way I can store HTML for next visit?

Comment: Storing html is nonsense. Store data in localStorage. If you want to provide an offline expierience, see "webapp" and "service worker"

Comment: Do not forget that local storage is *local*. Are you prepared for the stored data to be different depending on the browser / machine your users are currently using?

Comment: Yes, it should be different for each user. The application is a map (which uses googles maps), however, the popup has a button that says add to my itinerary, which loads data from their specific page from within the site the app sits on. I'd like that info present for when the user leaves and comes back. Does that make a little more sense? I apologize in advance if I am not making sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Yes, it should be different for each user.* But what about the same user in a different browser? I think that's what FrédéricHamidi was asking.

Comment: That is a good point. That isn't such a big deal in this case. Just as long as it would be the same for the user in the current browser (so no worry if they jump from (e.g.) firefox to chrome for whatever reason).

Answer (score 0):

I think if the data is different for each user you could store the data in a mysql database. If the data is coming from another page, you would only need to store the link to the other page in the database, and not all the data.

Each user on your page would have a different ID in the database, so they would only see their data. Assuming you have some kind of login procedure.

There isn't enough information to give a better answer at the moment.

Ok I will add to this. You can of course use cookies to store information on the client side. Of course cookies are limited to 4k for each cookie. Doesn't sound like much but that is 4000 characters of text. Like I said you don't want to be using cookies for a lot of text, but a few links and variables are fine to store.

To set a cookie do this

```
setcookie($cookiename, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
```

This is for 30 days, but it is possible to make the expiry date unlimited if you really wanted to.
To echo a cookie do this

```
echo $_COOKIE['cookiename'];
```

You can also store arrays in a cookies too.

```
$test = array(
0 => array('bill', 'ted'),
1 => array('alpha', 'romeo'),
2 => array('Chad', 'Something')
);

setcookie('names', $test);
```

However if a user logs in I would still suggest storing their data in a mysql database.

There are probably other methods also. Remember cookies only live in the browser that opened them. So if you view the page in one browser and then change browsers the cookie won't be there. Or if they visit from a different machine.

If the user has a login then it doesn't matter what machine visits your page.

Comment: Thomas, thanks so much for your response. I thought of that route, however, this part of the site should require no login, hence why I was thinking of using local storage or something like it. This is just a work in progress, but this test page http://marylandwine.com.64-207-179-169.c7gg-ww2l.accessdomain.com/wine-trail/ you can click on one of the two locations and add. I think you might see why I want to store that data upon a revisit a bit more. Please let me know if I can provide more info to help your answer. I really appreciate your response.

Comment: I have had a look at your page and couldn't work out what to click on to see your problem. On the plus side the page looks good, but on the negative side you need to spend some time optimizing your images for web. For example the picture called home-bg-edit.jpg is 325k. In a few seconds I had it saved to web from photoshop and got it down to 60k and it still looked good. BTW have you thought of using cookies. These are stored on the users machine, and can store arrays also.

Comment: Thomas - thanks so much for the compliments. Yes--need to optimize a few things. Photoshop does great, but have always liked this one: http://compressor.io. Anyway, if you click on a pin on map, click add, then click off, and click on pin and add again. (Instructions will be made clear when rest of page is finished). That info that loads into div, would be awesome to have there for next visit. Is this possible to do with cookies? If so, do you have any helpful articles I should read? Thank you so much!

Comment: Cookies are like SESSION variables but they stay on the client side. You can store arrays in cookies as well. Whether you should use cookies or not depends on how much data you need to store. You can also set cookies to expire after a certain time limit also. Cookies are not intended to store vast amounts of data, but it depends. If you are only storing a few llinks to news or something cookies may be the answer. Will look at your page again later.

Comment: Thanks for the great info, Thomas!! Yeah, on avarage, we are talking about storing a few links, a label (<span> tag) and a span with coordinates in it. In the meantime, I will start researching this route. Any info you can send about storing via cookies would be great, however, I am sure some simple googling will point me in the right direction, too. Every little bit helps.

Comment: I have added some info about cookies. Hope it helps

Comment: You're awesome, Thomas. Thanks for pointing me in a direction. Have a wonderful day.